# Backing up encrypted system disk (veracrypt) using Macrium Reflect

Tags: backup, encryption, veracrypt

New to imaging system disks and encrypting. I want to encrypt my C: system disk and then be able to back this up as easily and safely as possible. Using Veracrypt and Macrium Reflect. Done some digging and it gets quickly gets into having to use WinPE and MacriumPE and looks messy.

Can i encrypt my C:, then boot up. Open Reflect and simply image the C: and then encrypt that image? I'm guessing i'm missing something here and the image won't if needed. Also i am unsure how to test an image file, w/out potentially writing over my "live" system...I've read loads of and not getting very far. Would really appreciate some straight forward help.
Thanks

Comment: If the drive is encrypted, MR will image the encrypted drive, no more to do (it does not un-encrypt the drive when making the image), back up your encryption keys first. Change the hard drive if you can, restore the image to that drive if you can for testing purposes.

Comment: Just an "amen" to checking a drive image, particularly for an encrypted drive. Test at least the first few images to be sure they can be unencrypted after restoration.

Comment: If you encrypt your system drive and boot into that system any Reflect should only see the decrypted image as decryption is transparent. Hence performing a backup should save the decrypted data.

Comment: Robert, thanks for the reply. Does an encrypted direct not have a boot sector (i think this term is right) that helps boot the encrypted drive? And is so if imaging that when you  have booted it, would that not mean this boot sector is missing and so the image would not work?

Comment: Moab, i didn't make it clear, i want to boot into the encrypted system disk and then image it. I don't want to swap out my disk, i just want to image my system disk as a back up. Encryption keys...i don't know what they are. Something to learn!

Comment: Of course the image will not work out of the box as it is no longer encrypted which is what the Veracyrpt boot code expects. But the Macrium WinRE bootable environment has tools for fixing the boot loader and manager. Alternatively you can install a clean Windows 10 (let it prepare the disc and partitions + bootloader) before restoring the backup image (of course then you should only restore the partition containing the Windows system).

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification Robert, I appreciate it.